# calculate total time of listing items on mx:List Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, list, air

I want to get total time of listing items when I refresh data provider of List. I mean, when I change the data provider, how many milliseconds does it take to load both of new items. 
 for example: I have 3 items in data provider, it takes 2 milliseconds while loading to list. If I push 50 items, may be 15 milliseconds. 
 I checked the **mx.events.ListEvent** s, but couldn't find any proper solution. 
Any opinion appreciated, thanks

Comment: If anyone has a question, ask me. Some of idiots didn't understand anything, because they don't have any information,any idea about issue,they clicked undo reputation and escaped.never click and escape you idiots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create own class extends mx:List, see down:

```
package classes
{
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    import mx.controls.List;

    public class ListCustom extends List
    {

        private var _time:Number;

        public function ListCustom()
        {
            super();
        }

        override public function set dataProvider(value:Object):void
        {
            _time = getTimer();

            super.dataProvider = value;
        }

        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            if (!isNaN(_time))
            {
                var delay:Number = getTimer() - _time;

                _time = NaN;

                trace("delay", delay);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much,when I have enough,will thank you with reputations, I'll apply this as soon as possible.

Comment: I applied this solution and worked for me to test how many it takes loading data providers.Thanks one more time, you showed me how to create solution to this kind of problems.

Comment: If you are agree with answer, can you accept it as the best answer? thanks